# scala Class.forName pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am newbie using scala .
I am trying to use pattern matching with reflection:

```
abstract class Person{
val name:String,
val age:Int
}
case class Man (name:String,age:Int,workPlace:String) extends Person

val aclass = Class.forName("man")
aclass match{
 case m:Man => println("this is a man class")
 case p:Person => println("Person")
 case _ => println("Nothing")
}
```

I am always getting to default part ("Nothing") and to the correct match (Man) . what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a typo in question or you're okay with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: man` in your actual code (java class names are case sensitive)? And by the way, your Person class should not even compile because of comma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to use the full and properly cased class name. Second, `Class.forName` returns a `Class[_]`, not an instance of the class you give it. Take a look at modifications to your code that I made to get a clearer picture:

```
  abstract class Person {
    val name: String //removed comma
    val age: Int
  }

  case class Man(name: String, age: Int, workPlace: String) extends Person

  val manClassName = classOf[Man].getName //get the proper name of the class

  println("Man class name: %s".format(manClassName))

  val aclass = Class.forName(manClassName) //returns Class[Man]

  aclass match {
    case m: Class[Man] => println("this is a man class") //Pattern match on Class[Man]
    case p: Class[Person] => println("Person")
    case _ => println("Nothing")
  }
```

Comment: Thanks , that works! BTW what is class[_] is that general class ?

Comment: It's just a way of denoting that Class is a type constructor and takes a type. So in your case it's Class[Man].

Comment: Accidently I upvoted. not sure how this answer makes sense though. As its matching to `Class[_]` where there is a type erasure happening. See how misleading is this? ```scala> Class.forName(classOf[String].getName) match {
             case m: Class[Man] => println("this is a man class") //Pattern match on Class[Man]
             case p: Class[Person] => println("Person")
             case _ => println("Nothing")
           } 
this is a man class```

Answer (score -1):

Few problems with your code. Maybe I'm not understanding what you're doing with Class.forName(String) so I changed things a bit.

First, use case classes for these so you get your getters and setters for encapsulation.

```
sealed trait Person
case class Man (name:String,age:Int,workPlace:String) extends Person
```

Next, Class.forName returns a Class, not an object.
So you need to instantiate by calling the Constructor of Man

```
val man = Man("Jo", 24, "anywhere")
```

Then you can pattern match on that:

```
man match{
 case m:Man => println("this is a man class")
 case p:Person => println("Person")
 case _ => println("Nothing")
}
```

It will match the first case that hits though so make sure you order man and person cases how you want them.
For reflection, you'll want to look at TypeTags and ClassTags

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html